# Lua get Instance in an instance where the name matches a string

Tags: lua, roblox

I am a javascript developer and am starting to use lua.
When i write code such as:

```
var obj = {
  prop: "Hello World"
}
, propName = "prop";

//and to fetch the value:
console.log(obj[propName]);
/as apposed to:
console.log(obj.propName) //undefined
```

in lua is there any way to get a property of an Instance that has the same name as a string.

```
--i.e:
game.Workspace.<INSERT VARIABLE VALUE HERE>.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 100
```

P.S i am using lua for roblox if that makes any changes

Answer (score 1):

I don't known roblox but try this:

```
game.Workspace[myvar].Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 100
```

In this sense, Lua is like JavaScript.